# How to avoid dquote when using twarc?

Tags: twitter, terminal, twarc2

I'm trying to get Tweets using twarc2 on terminal like this.

```
twarc2 search --archive --start-time "2017-10-16”  ‘(“#metoo”) -is:retweet lang:en' --limit 1000000 tweets.json
```

However, after I put the request above, I get

```
dquote>
```

It seems that this appears when you use a single quotation and a double quotation. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the double quote is not necessary. otherwise you can use the escape \ "

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have a single quote ending the command (or, you’ve used a smart quote not a straight quote).